Need title, hollow earth movie, 2000+
I remember seeing this movie on TV. I've gone through all the hollow earth lists that I could find.
There was this group of people going down into earth. I think the setting was 50 years or so ago. The people going in had torches for light, nothing electric.
I vaguely remember that the leader? Of the group needed some money for something, equipment maybe, and he boxed to get it while his friend placed a bet.
I remember them standing at a crack in the earth and one of them said something like "my new invention" and "gravity machine". They threw their bags down and descended with ropes.
I vaguely remember they where in a cave, there was some fluid dripping down. Ended up being burnable and them having torches resulted in an explosion.
I remember a scene where they come out to a beach and you could see pillars  reaching up to the crust? forming the cave. There was light and wind in that cave.
I remember one of them saying that he believed that the surface of the earth was also a cave.
I think they crossed the sea or lake.
They found people down there. If I remember correctly they where Indian-ish. And I mean the original american ones, very primitive. They got in trouble with them. They had to escape and one of them, in the middle of the escape, ran back because he lost a crystal or something valuable that he found earlier, I don't remember if he got out or not.
Some of them where scientists or archaeologists I think.
For the time range, judging by my own age and memory, the quality of special effects and the camera image in the first place, I'd say its a 2000 or later movie at least. I could be wrong.
I hope I gave enough details. Any help would be awesome.
Sidenote: I don't remember anything like dinosaurs or crazy insects or any other crazy life forms.

@Walt yes thats it! Sorry about it being duplicate. Thanks alot!
